# How to stop win8 from collecting error info when BSODing?

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, bsod

What's worse than having a machine BSOD? Having to wait 25 minutes for this:

```
Your pc ran into a problem and needs to restart. We are just collecting some
error info, and then we'll restart for you.
```

How can get rid of the error info collection. I know where the problem is, I don't desire this.

Comment: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/automatic-memory-dump-settings-windows-8

Comment: This is it! Thank you! Care to post it as an answer or shall I do it myself?

Comment: Answer coming up ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `Write debugging information` to `None` (No memory dumps).

See below for complete instructions.

---

Source [Automatic Memory Dump Settings on Windows 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/automatic-memory-dump-settings-windows-8)

> If you want to change Automatic Memory Dump settings here is how you
>   can do it.
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and click on `System`.
> 2. Next click on `Advance System Settings`.
> 3. Under Start up and Recovery, click on `Settings`.
> 4. There you can see a drop-down menu where it says "Write debugging information".
> 5. Here you can select the option you want. The options offered are:
>
>    - None (No memory dumps)
>    - Small memory dump
>    - Kernel memory dump
>    - Complete memory dump
>    - Automatic memory dump

The above link includes screenshots.